# pass JVM args to clover in a ant script

Tags: java, ant, cloveretl

I call runGraph class from CloverETL in a ANT script like this

```
      <java classname="org.jetel.main.runGraph" fork="true" failonerror="true">

           <arg value="${canadapostdir}/metadata/CanadaPostADDTypes34.grf"/>
                    <classpath>
                            <pathelement path="${ear.lib}/clover.jar" />
                            <pathelement path="${ear.libext}/oracle.jdbc/ojdbc6.jar" />
                            <pathelement path="${ear.libext}/mysql.jdbc/mysql-connector-java-3.0.15-ga-bin.jar" />
                            <fileset dir="${ear.lib}">
                                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                            </fileset>
                    </classpath>
            </java>
```

When clover start I can see that in the log :

```
    [java] [Clover] starting WatchDog thread ...
    [java] [WatchDog] Thread started.
    [java] [WatchDog] Running on 16 CPU(s) max available memory for JVM 3005703 kB
    [java] [Clover] Initializing phase: 0
    [java]  all edges initialized successfully...
    [java]  initializing nodes:
    [java]     INPUT ...OK
    [java]     TYPEFILTER ...OK
    [java]     REF ...OK
    [java]     OUTPUT ...OK
    [java] [Clover] phase: 0 initialized successfully.
    [java] [WatchDog] Starting up all nodes in phase [0]
    [java] [WatchDog]   INPUT ... started
    [java] [WatchDog]   TYPEFILTER ... started
    [java] [WatchDog]   REF ... started
    [java] [WatchDog]   OUTPUT ... started
    [java] [WatchDog] Sucessfully started all nodes in phase!
```

My question is : how can I make clover run with more memory than 3005703 kB ?There is actually 100gig of free ram on the server that this script is running.

EDIT : I know for what I see that clover is not running on a separate jvm and that it use all the free memory availble on the current JVM instance I guess. I need to find a way to start clover on a separate jvm which I can pass -Xms10240m -Xmx10240m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<jvmarg>` nested elements are used to pass JVM arguments:

```
<java classname="org.jetel.main.runGraph" fork="true" failonerror="true">

       <arg value="${canadapostdir}/metadata/CanadaPostADDTypes34.grf"/>
       <jvmarg value="-Xms1024M"/>
       <jvmarg value="-Xmx10240M"/>
       <classpath>
               <pathelement path="${ear.lib}/clover.jar" />
               <pathelement path="${ear.libext}/oracle.jdbc/ojdbc6.jar" />
               <pathelement path="${ear.libext}/mysql.jdbc/mysql-connector-java-3.0.15-ga-bin.jar" />
                   <fileset dir="${ear.lib}">
                         <include name="*.jar"/>
                   </fileset>
       </classpath>
</java>
```

You *are* executing the class in another VM. That's what `fork=true` means.